# Yii2 CORS requests

Tags: rest, yii2, cors

I created a simple restful api with yii2, every request worked fine on my local web server. Then I uploaded to shared hosting and half of my requests started to return 404 error. Only GET, POST and OPTIONS requests work as they supposed to.

Url rules:

```
'class' => \yii\rest\UrlRule::class,
'pluralize' => true,
'controller' => 'todo',
'patterns' => [
    'DELETE {id}'    => 'delete-todo',
    'POST {id}'      => 'create-todo',
    'PUT,PATCH {id}' => 'update-todo',
    'OPTIONS {id}'   => 'options'
],
```

Let take this rule:

```
'DELETE {id}' => 'delete-todo',
```

If I change it to this:

```
'GET {id}' => 'delete-todo',
```

and send GET request it will work, but why doesn't it work with DELETE request?

And why does it work properly on my local web server and doesn't on shared hosting?

Comment: Is your server allowing the http delete verb? any error message in its log files?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 'enableStrictParsing' => false' and set 'pluralize' => false, in your url manager rule.